# Make a memoryview read-only in Python pre-3.8

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.3

Python 3.8 added the [`memoryview.toreadonly()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.toreadonly) method. But is there a way to make a read-only memoryview in previous version of python -- specifically Python 3.5 and 3.3?

For a little bit more background, I use memoryviews to share parts of large binary blobs between objects. Sometimes the blob is an in-memory `byte` object, but sometimes it is also a read/write mmapped file. And I would like to avoid modifications by mistake of the underlying file through the memoryviews.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a read-only wrapper/proxy class for `memoryview` to deny setter and deleter calls. For getter calls, make sure to wrap the sliced view in another instance of the read-only proxy class if a slice is requested:

```
class ReadonlyMemoryView:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.view = memoryview(obj)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        value = self.view[index]
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return self.__class__(value)
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        raise TypeError('cannot modify read-only memory')

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        raise TypeError('cannot modify read-only memory')

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.view, name)
```

so that:

```
m = ReadonlyMemoryView(bytearray(range(10)))
print(m[3:7][1:3].tolist())
m[3] = 1
```

outputs:

```
[4, 5]
```

and produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "prog.py", line 12, in __setitem__
TypeError: cannot modify read-only memory
```

Demo of the code running on Python 2.7: https://ideone.com/2iivHt